# Using R with Jupyter notebook installation

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, jupyter-irkernel

I have installed R from the official site and want to use it from jupyter notebook and jupyterlab. For that i have installed IRkernal in R using:

```r
install.packages('IRkernel')
```

and then when I type `IRkernel::installspec(user = FALSE)` to make this installation visible globally,
I get following error:

```r
Error in IRkernel::installspec(user = FALSE) : 
  jupyter-client has to be installed but “jupyter kernelspec --version” exited with code 127.
In addition: Warning message:
In system2("jupyter", c("kernelspec", "--version"), FALSE, FALSE) :
  '"jupyter"' not found
```

I have jupyter installation on miniconda and I don't want to use the conda distribution of R. What should I do?

Comment: Anaconda promotes itself as the package manager for Python and Jupyter.  It's not.  Anaconda and miniconda are entirely unnecessary for the installation of Python, Jupyter Notebook and Jupyter Lab.  Order of things: 1) Install python. Choose custom install -  C:\python37   2) In Windows, create a environmental path (C:\python37\scripts\, C:\python37\python.exe)  3) From cmd prompt, upgrade pip.  4) From cmd prompt, run pip and  install Jupyter notebook. 5) From cmd, run Jupyter (test run)  6) From RStudio, Rkernel::installspec() 6)  From RStudio, IRkernel::installspec(user = FALSE)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that but this question is for someone who already has an anaconda installation and doesn't want a separate jupyter installation in pure python env. I figured it out after posting the question and hence posted an answer. @Gray

Comment: @Gray - isn't pip just another package manager, like anaconda? What's the benefit of using it?

Comment: Put simply, Anaconda puts a huge layer of unknown   between the user and the software.  Without Anaconda, a user will learn how to install python and then choose which packages to install using pip.  This also forces the user to use the command prompt, update the system environmental variables, and to know exactly what is installed on the pc.   Owning these skills is absolutely necessary for anyone to advance in programming or computer science.   There is no such thing as a Wizard of Oz  who's managing your computer for you.  Only data entry jobs await those who do not fully own their computer

Comment: @Gray Yes that's true but not anaconda is mostly used by data science and ML peeps and most of the time they don't care about what is happening in the background. They just want to use the packages and don't bother installing everything individually.

Answer (score 3):

The command to setup IRkernel has to be run in the same environment as the jupyter installation. Due to this, It won't work with R.exe directly. For this, you have to run the command `IRkernel::installspec(user=FALSE)` **in the Anaconda prompt**.

Comment: How do you run an R command in the Anaconda prompt?

Comment: @MichalJ.Figurski Talking about windows, If you have R as PATH or env variable then you can directly launch the R kernel from any command-line be it the anaconda prompt too then you can type these commands. If not then you can change directory to path_to_r_install/bin/ and there you will find R.exe you can run that executable in the command line and use the R kernel. If you are using Linux then this problem should not arise because there is same terminal for everything (but I am not sure).

Comment: @MichalJ.Figurski Did you manage to install using R with jupyter? I just posted about the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63816823/using-r-on-jupyter-on-mac-catalina-making-the-installation-visible-globally-doe

Comment: Two small things.  First, the answer helped me, thanks. Just that with R we need to type "FALSE" or "F" instead of "False". Second,  about the comment on how to run R command in the Anaconda Prompt,  in the prompt, type "R", and then you are in R, then type your R commands.