# Using R on Jupyter on Mac Catalina: Making the installation visible globally does not work

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, jupyter-irkernel

I am trying to use R on jupyter. I have run the commands in my terminal from [here](https://www.chrisjmendez.com/2018/12/04/configure-jupyter-notebook-to-work-with-r/). Everything works well until trying to make the installation visible globally. Whether I use `IRkernel::installspec()` or `IRkernel::installspec(user = FALSE)` (as recommended [here](https://irkernel.github.io/installation/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63463273/using-r-with-jupyter-notebook-installation)), I still get the error message:

[image]

My macOS is Catalina 10.15.6

What's the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick: do this locally only. Uninstall everything and start from scratch. I had to do this once and wrote a guide for myself in case I had to repeat this in the future. You can find my guide here: http://websmelter.com/stats/setting-up-jupyter-notebook-with-custom-r-on-a-mac/

I was not able to do this globally on a Mac. It works on Windows, but Mac is tricky. I used the .pkg method for miniconda installation, and the option to "install for all users" was greyed out.

Perhaps if you use the manual method, this could be done...

Comment: Thank you so much, thanks for putting it into a clear guide! You mention it took you 2 hours to uninstall Anaconda. Any recommendation (or guide :)) on how to do it efficiently and in a clean way?

Comment: For uninstalling Anaconda, here is a good guide: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/  But (!!!) before you touch Anaconda (start any uninstallation steps), download anaconda-clean and run it. The guide (linked here) has those steps reversed. It took me hours to clean up that mess...